# Discrete Mathematics question..

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Q: What is the negative proposition of $\forall x>0,\ x+\frac{1}{x}\ge1$?

A.$\exists\ x>0,\ x+\frac{1}{x}<1$

B.$\exists\ x>0,\ x\le 0$

C.$\exists\ x\le 0,\ x+\frac{1}{x}<1$

D.$\exists\ x\le 0,\ x\le 0$

By the way, my answer is **A**, but my friend told me the correct is **B**. I don't know why.

Comment: I don't know why someone is claiming the answer is B. The answer is indeed A.

Comment: @SangchulLee The solution to the question says, you need to compute the solution set for $x$, and then negate it.

Comment: That's not what mathematicians would think about 'negation of a proposition'. Although B can be proved from A (and hence they are logically equivalent) in the system of real numbers, this logical equivalence is not part of what is asked in the question.

Comment: Moreover, A is always the negation of the original statement assuming the negation rules for the quantifier and the equivalence $\neg(a<b)\iff(a\geq b)$ regardless of the interpretation of the binary operator $+$ and the relations $<$, and $\geq$, but B may fail to be logically equivalent to A if we give idiosyncratic interpretations to those symbols.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you for your explanation, and please forgive me, I would like to retranslate the question, if the question is "What is the negation of $\forall x>0,\ x+\frac{1}{x}\ge1$?" Is the answer still A？(I am confused the difference between `the negation of SOMETHING` and `the negation proposition of SOMETHING`)

Comment: There's no difference in meaning, just in wording. 'The negation proposition of smth.' just sounds more awkward.